# how do i update the sqlite database created for android?

Tags: android, database

i am creating an app that needs a database. i created it using sqlite database browser, which means the app i created, imports the database i created into the phone.

and what i've learnt before, is if i did any changes to the database using the browser, i have to uninstall the app from my phone/emulator so that it make the changes.

so the problem came. what happen if after i upload the app to the market, and realized that i need to update the table ??? and also, another problem is that user have to enter some data and save it into a table of the database.

so is there a way to update my database & yet keep the data that the user entered in the table ???

my database helper code is below. pls help...thanks alot !

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/test.test/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "TestDatabase";

private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase; 

private final Context myContext;

/**
 *  # Constructor #
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}//constructor  

/**
 *  # Create Database #
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 */
public void createDatabase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();

    if(dbExist)
    {
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }//if

    else
    {
        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try 
        {
            copyDatabase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }//catch
    }//else

}//createDatabase

private boolean checkDatabase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try
    {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch(SQLiteException e) {

        //database does't exist yet.

    }//catch

    if(checkDB != null) 
    { 
        checkDB.close();

    }//if

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;

}//checkDatabase


private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;

    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0)
    {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}//copyDatabase

// # open database #
public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}//openDatabase

@Override
public synchronized void close() 
{
    if(myDatabase != null)
        myDatabase.close();

    super.close();

}//close

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public List<String> selectData
    (String tableName, String [] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
            String groupBy, String having, String orderBy) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor cursor = this.myDatabase.query(tableName, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
    {
        do 
        {
            list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        }

        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) 
    {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return list;

}//selectData

public void insertData (String tableName, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values) {

    try
    {
        myDatabase.insert(tableName, nullColumnHack, values);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error :","unable to insert data");
    }//catch

}//insertData

//edit row
public void updateData (String tableName, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {

    try
    {
        myDatabase.update(tableName, values, whereClause, whereArgs);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error :","unable to update data");
    }//catch
}//updateData

public void deleteRow (String tableName, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {

    try
    {
        myDatabase.delete(tableName, whereClause, whereArgs);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error :","unable to delete row");
    }//catch
}//deleteRow
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

is for.

[Documentation here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: The examples in the notepad tutorial are useful if you haven't found them yet: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html  just be aware that your onUpgrade function can just add columns to an existing table using standard SQL commands rather than wiping the whole thing as their example does.

Comment: sorry for waiting so long to reply, as I asked the question early hopping to get some answer before doing it. the problem is, i have no idea how to deal with it. i've seen the notepad tutorial, but somehow i didnt saw the onUpgrade method.